# Using Except on DataFrame in Apache Spark 2.1.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Does except work correctly on Spark DataFrames?

In the Spark shell I created a trivial DataFrame with three strings: "a", "b", "c". Limit(1) is assigned to row1 which correctly yields Array([a]). Then row1 is used as a parameter to the extend method on the grfDF DataFrame yielding tail1. Shouldn't tail1 be a new DataFrame of Array([b], [c])?

Why does tail1 still contain "a" and has "b" removed?

```
scala> grfDF.collect
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([a], [b], [c])                   

scala> val row1 = grfDF.limit(1)
row1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [sub: string]

scala> row1.collect
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([a])

scala> val tail1 = grfDF.except(row1).collect
tail1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([c], [a])
```

The DataFrame is created as follows:

```
    case class Grf(sub: String)
    def toGrf = (grf: Seq[String]) => Grf(grf(0))
    val sourceList = Array("a", "b", "c")
    val grfRDD = sc.parallelize(sourceList).map(_.split(",")).map(toGrf(_))
    val grfDF = spark.createDataFrame(grfRDD)
    grfDF.createOrReplaceTempView("grf")
```

Then I try to pop off a row:

```
    val row1 = grfDF.limit(1)
    row1.collect 
    val tail1 = grfDF.except(row1)
    tail1.collect
```

Comment: Needs a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I feel like this story starts in Chapter 2. Could you please share how you constructed `grfDF`?

Comment: If you are able to see `[a]` in `row1.collect` then `tail1` will always give `Array([c], [b])`

Comment: with your code, i get always Array([c], [b]) as result

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do similar things in spark shell. Please try the same code again as the result I am getting is Array([b],[c]). Please see the below code:

```
scala> val sourceList=Array("a","b","c")
sourceList: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> val grfRDD = sc.parallelize(sourceList)
grfRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:29

val grfDF = grfRDD.toDF()
grfDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> grfDF
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> val row1 = grfDF.limit(1)
row1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> row1
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

row1.collect()
res2: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([a])

scala> val tail = grfDF.except(row1)
tail: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> tail.collect()
res6: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([b], [c])
```